# LWC vertical progressbar - problem in Previous and Next button logic

Tags: lightning-web-components, javascript, html, component

i am new to lwc, i created a component for vertical progress bar, but i am facing issue in previous and next button.
1.Next button works from a to e, ( a->b>c->d->e), but for the last button i am supposed to press it twice to reach the "f" step
2.previous button problem - after reaching to last step, if i press the previous button ,it wont come its previous state (from f step to e step, it wont move)
[image: lightning web component for vertical bar - problem in next and prevbutton]
plz help me with logic , and i have given my html and javascript code below

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="Vertical Progress Indicator">
        <!-- <c-dynamic-vertical-progress-indicator indicator-type='path'
            step-list={stepVertical}
          current-step ={currentVertical} ></c-dynamic-vertical-progress-indicator><br>partiton -->


        <c-dynamic-vertical-progress-indicator indicator-type='vertical'
            step-list={stepVertical}
          current-step ={currentVertical} ></c-dynamic-vertical-progress-indicator>

        <div class="slds-m-vertical_medium">
            <lightning-button label="Back" class="slds-m-left_x-small" onclick={handlePrev}></lightning-button>
            <template if:false={isSelectStep4}>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Next" onclick={handleNext}></lightning-button>
            </template>
            <!-- <template if:true={isSelectStep4}>
                <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-m-left_x-small" label="Finish" onclick={handleFinish}></lightning-button>
            </template> -->
        </div>
    </lightning-card>
    
</template>
```

Javascript code starts here:

```
import { LightningElement,track, wire } from 'lwc';
export default class ButtonComponent extends LightningElement {
    @wire(MessageContext)
    MessageContext;
    currentStepCount=0;
    countTotalSteps;
    stepListArray;   
    stepVertical=['a','b','c','d','e','f'];
    @track currentVertical;

    connectedCallback(){
        this.queryVerticalSteps();
        this.stepListArray = this.stepVertical;
        this.currentVertical =  this.stepListArray[0];
        this.countTotalSteps = this.stepListArray.length;        
        console.log('CURRENT STEP====>'+this.currentVertical);
        console.log('CURRENT STEP NO===>'+this.currentStepCount);
        // console.log('TOTAL STEPS=====>'+this.countTotalSteps);

    }

    queryVerticalSteps(){
        getIntegrationResponse()
            
    }
    handleNext(){  

        if(this.currentStepCount != this.countTotalSteps){

        this.currentStepCount =this.currentStepCount + 1;
        this.currentVertical = this.stepListArray[this.currentStepCount];       
        console.log('CURRENT STEP====>'+this.currentVertical);
        console.log('CURRENT STEP NO===>'+this.currentStepCount);
        this.template.querySelector('c-dynamic-vertical-progress-indicator').mainMethod();
        }
    }
    handlePrev(){  
        if(this.currentStepCount != 0){
        this.template.querySelector('c-dynamic-vertical-progress-indicator').mainMethod();
        console.log(this.stepListArray);
        this.countTotalSteps = this.stepListArray.length;
        this.currentStepCount =this.currentStepCount - 1;
        this.currentVertical = this.stepListArray[this.currentStepCount];
        console.log('CURRENT STEP====>'+this.currentVertical);
       // console.log('CURRENT STEP NO===>'+this.currentStepCount);
    
        }
        
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated my answer as I missed the original request.

I used a regular progress indicator, as I don't have your source.

Essence of the solution: Use Getters where possible. If you use a getter, you have less state to maintain, and subsequently, less errors are possible.

In this solution, I use a getter to get the current state. The getter uses a hidden stage field that can be incremented twice at the last step.

```
<lightning-progress-indicator current-step={currentStep} type="path" variant="base">
  <template for:each={steps} for:item="step">
      <lightning-progress-step label={step.label} value={step.value} key={step.label}></lightning-progress-step>
  </template>
</lightning-progress-indicator>

<div class="slds-var-m-vertical_medium">
  <lightning-button label="Back" class="slds-var-m-left_x-small" onclick={handlePrevious}></lightning-button>
  <lightning-button variant="brand" class="slds-var-m-left_x-small" label={nextText} onclick={handleNext}></lightning-button>
</div>
```

Javascript internals:

```
base = ['a','b','c','d','e','f'];

get steps(){
  return this.base.map( option => { return {'label':option,'value':option, 'key':option}});
}

get nextText(){
  return this._currentStepInternal > this.base.length ? 'Finish' : 'Next';
}

_currentStepInternal = 1;
get currentStep(){
  if (this._currentStepInternal === this.base.length|| this._currentStepInternal === this.base.length + 1 ){
    return this.steps[this.steps.length -1].label;
  }
  return this.steps[this._currentStepInternal-1].label;
}

handleNext(){
  if (this._currentStepInternal > this.base.length){
    //do finish
  }
  else {
    this._currentStepInternal++;
  }
}

handlePrevious(){
  this._currentStepInternal--;
}
```

Note the getters and an only one state variable. Your custom component won't be very different from this in implementation - one possible difference - current step is the step `value` or `label` rather than index.

Comment: I have done the above suggestion, still its NEXT button is not working for e and f step . please any inputs or suggestions?

Comment: Completely redid my answer. Try now.